# How can I merge two dataframes outside the intersection of the data?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe of presidential candiates, their received donation amount, and the states where the donations came from (contbr_st).

However, the state includes non state abbreviations such as AA, FF, FM as shown below. And, I have a single column dataframe of 50 state abbreviations.

dataframe below is "total"

```
cand_nm    Obama, Barack  Romney, Mitt
contbr_st                             
AA              56405.00        135.00
AB               2048.00           NaN
AE              42973.75       5680.00
AK             281840.15      86204.24
AL             543123.48     527303.51
AP              37130.50       1655.00
AR             359247.28     105556.00
AS               2955.00           NaN
AZ            1506476.98    1888436.23
CA           23824984.24   11237636.60
CO            2132429.49    1506714.12
CT            2068291.26    3499475.45
DC            4373538.80    1025137.50
DE             336669.14      82712.00
FF                   NaN      99030.00
FL            7318178.58    8338458.81
FM                600.00           NaN
```

Dataframe below is 50 state, it is "state"

```
   state
0     AL
1     AK
2     AZ
3     AR
4     CA
5     CO
6     CT
7     DC
8     DE
9     FL
10    GA
11    HI
12    ID
13    IL
14    IN
15    IA
16    KS
17    KY
18    LA
19    ME
20    MD
21    MA
22    MI
23    MN
24    MS
25    MO
26    MT
27    NE
28    NV
29    NH
30    NJ
31    NM
32    NY
33    NC
34    ND
35    OH
36    OK
37    OR
38    PA
39    RI
40    SC
41    SD
42    TN
43    TX
44    UT
45    VT
46    VA
47    WA
48    WV
49    WI
50    WY
```

Is there a simple way in Pandas to merge these two dataframes to discard the intersecting states, and keep the non state data from the original dataframe ('total')?

so my expected output would include non state abbreviation data as below

```
cand_nm    Obama, Barack  Romney, Mitt
contbr_st                             
AA              56405.00        135.00
AP              37130.50       1655.00
FF                   NaN      99030.00
FM                600.00           NaN 
.
.
```

The only way I can think of is convert state list from each dataframe, convert to set, use the difference() method. Then, convert the result to dataframe, and merge with the "total" dataframe.

Comment: `state.merge(total,left_on='state',right_index=True,how='left')` ? not sure what you mean by *merge these two dataframes to discard the intersecting states, and keep what is only in the "total" dataframe* , it would help if you shorten your example and post an expected output

Comment: `total.loc[~total.index.isin(state.index)]`?

Comment: total.loc[~total.index.isin(state.index)] this worked like a charm. Thanks!